# remove switch from cellForRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, tableview

**I'm working on multiple section tableView and I managed to make some progress for making it scalable (Easy to maintain). but I still can't figure out a way to replace switch statement

```swift
 let itemType = viewModel.items[indexPath.section].type
        let item = viewModel.items[indexPath.section]


        switch itemType {
// General cell
        case .general:
        let generalCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"generalCell" , for: indexPath) as! GeneralCell
              generalCell.bind(viewModel: item, index: indexPath.row)
            return generalCell
// Info cell
        case .infos:
  let infoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"infoCell" , for: indexPath) as! InfoCell
                infoCell.bind(viewModel: item, index: indexPath.row)
            return infoCell
// Friend cell
        case .friends:
let friendCell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"friendCell" , for: indexPath) as! FriendCell
friendCell.bind(viewModel: item, index: indexPath.row)
            return friendCell
        }
```

this is the code I use in my cellForRowAt function. can you suggest a better way [ a replacement for switch statement ]

Comment: This code has at least 3 problems that will avoid compiling. Show your real code.

Comment: @Desdenova i was using protocols for identifiers. i changed the sample code.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the switch statement? There will need to be some conditional logic if you have different cell types.

Comment: @Chris if I have 10 different cell I have to have a +40 lines of code and that's hard to maintain

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create cells that you don't need:

```
let itemType = viewModel.items[indexPath.section].type
let item = viewModel.items[indexPath.section]

switch itemType {
case .general:
    let generalCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as GeneralCell
    generalCell.bind(viewModel: item, index: indexPath.row)
    return generalCell
case .infos:
    let infoCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as InfoCell
    infoCell.bind(viewModel: item, index: indexPath.row)
    return infoCell
case .friends:
    let friendCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath) as FriendCell
    friendCell.bind(viewModel: item, index: indexPath.row)
    return friendCell
}
```

Comment: You can't dequeue cells without an identifier.

Comment: All cells are needed. in your code, there is still a switch statement that I'm trying to get rid of.

Comment: @desdenova   identifiers are set through extensions and protocols  and they work fine